# unfortunately has stopped error with ViewPager?

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I'm trying to create a an app that first show a `ListView` with many items, when the user click on a specific item then the next activity will open to show images with a `ViewPager`.

At the beginning I create the `ViewPager` and I was able to swipe between images, but then when I try to create a new other app that firstly shown the `ListView` and after clicking on its item show the `ViewPager` the app stops and show this message: "Unfortunately has stopped". App starts showing items on list but when user clicks on app stop working. I tried to find the error with the **LogCat** but it doesn't show any thing I don't know why!!!.

**Main class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

    ListView itemListView;
    String[] values;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        itemListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.itemListView);
        values=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.values);

        itemListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values));
        itemListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SwipeActivity.class);

        switch(itemListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()){

        case "First":
            i.putExtra("nextActivity", 1);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        case "Second":
            i.putExtra("nextActivity", 2);
            startActivity(i);
            break;



        }

    }
}
```

**SwipeActivity" class**

```
public class SwipeActivity extends Activity{


ViewPager vp;
Table_customSwipeAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    vp=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    adapter=new Table_customSwipeAdapter(this);
    vp.setAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

**Table_customSwipeAdapter" class**

```
public class Table_customSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter{


private int[] image_resources={R.drawable.i1,R.drawable.i2,R.drawable.i3,R.drawable.i4,R.drawable.i5};
private Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


public Table_customSwipeAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx=ctx;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return image_resources.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return (arg0==(LinearLayout)arg1);
}


public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position){

    layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View item_view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_table_custom_swipe_adapter, container,false);

    ImageView imageView=(ImageView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    TextView textView=(TextView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_count);
    imageView.setImageResource(image_resources[position]);
    textView.setText("Image "+(position+1));
    container.addView(item_view);

    return item_view;

}


public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object){
    container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);

}

}
```

I think that the exception is thrown when I call the `Table_customSwipeAdapter` class, but I don't know why the app works before adding `ListView`?

Comment: It's nice you provided code, but please also add the logcat with an [edit]

Comment: The logcat doesn't show any thing!! @cricket_007

Comment: It should. Your app doesn't crash for no reason. Please filter by your package name and look at it while the "app has stopped" dialog is opened. Don't dismiss that until you copy the logs

Comment: You appear to be using `R.layout.activity_main` for both Activity classes you have shown here. I assume that is incorrect, and probably the cause of the error

Comment: Oh... How I did not pay attention, I was call the activity_main instead of the activity_swipe .... Thanks alot @cricket_007